# AlertView Not Rotating in ios7?

Tags: ios, ios7, uialertview, uiinterfaceorientation

Our app only supports Landscape mode and need to support iOS5.1 & 6.0 & 7.0. Bynow, we've set the rootviewcontroller and 
                   **BaseSdk : 7.0**
                   **DeploymentTarget : 5.1**

Our App is working fine in iOS 5 and ios 6. 
But in iOS7, when the alertview is present and the user rotating to portrait, alertview also rotating to potrait, which not happens on iOS5 & 6. 
And also once alertview went to portrait, it doesn't rotate to landscape.

**Note:** My ViewController's orientation is fine. It is always only supports Landscape.

Comment: Where are you calling your alert view? Can we see some code?

Comment: @Robert
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
if (landScapeOnlyView) {
  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight      || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
 }
  else if (openView) {
 return YES;
  }
  return NO;
}

This is the code that i'm using for orientation.

Comment: I had a similar but almost opposite problem - AlertView rotating when it shouldn't. Question and solution (move calling of AlertView method to `ViewDidAppear`) are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833129/prevent-alertview-from-auto-rotating

Comment: @Robert I Solved the issue by implementing the -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations method. 
when the alertView appears, supportedInterfaceOrientations method is called, where as for other views - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOri‌​entation called. That's making the problem for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Solved the issue by implementing the supportedInterfaceOrientations Method:
Before i've used only

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if (landscapeOnly) {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Now i've implemented supportedInterfaceOrientations method also along with that. Because when alert view comes, supportedInterfaceOrientations is called automatically.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    if (landscapeOnly) {
        return ((1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
    }
    else{
        return ((1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown));
    }
}
```

( 1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) is for UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape

Answer (score 0):

Here is some links that can help you:

[iOS 7 Viewcontroller not rotating when alertview is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521085/ios-7-viewcontroller-not-rotating-when-alertview-is-present)

[iOS 7: UIAlertView created in UIActionSheet delegate function cannot auto rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491060/ios-7-uialertview-created-in-uiactionsheet-delegate-function-cannot-auto-rotate)

Hope this is helps you.